# Client-side mutation with RANGE_ADD type doesn't include edge inside request payload

Tags: relayjs, graphql

I'm trying to create new object using client-side mutation described below:

```
import Relay from 'react-relay'

export default class CreateThemeMutation extends Relay.Mutation {

  static fragments = {
    admin: () => Relay.QL`fragment on Admin { id }`,
  };

  getMutation() {
    return Relay.QL`mutation { createTheme }`
  }

  getFatQuery() {
    return Relay.QL`
      fragment on CreateThemePayload {
        admin { themes }
        themeEdge
      }
    `
  }

  getVariables() {
    return {
      name: this.props.name,
    }
  }

  getConfigs() {
    return [{
      type: 'RANGE_ADD',
      parentName: 'admin',
      parentID: this.props.admin.id,
      connectionName: 'themes',
      edgeName: 'themeEdge',
      rangeBehaviors: {
        '': 'append',
      },
    }]
  }

}
```

Root query field `admin` is quite similar to `viewer` so this shouldn't be a problem. The problem is I haven't found `themeEdge` (which I believe should present) within the request payload (`admin { themes }` is there though):

```
query: "mutation CreateThemeMutation($input_0:CreateThemeInput!){createTheme(input:$input_0){clientMutationId,...F3}} fragment F0 on Admin{id} fragment F1 on Admin{id,...F0} fragment F2 on Admin{_themes2gcwoM:themes(first:20,query:""){count,pageInfo{hasNextPage,hasPreviousPage,startCursor,endCursor},edges{node{id,name,createdAt},cursor}},id,...F1} fragment F3 on CreateThemePayload{admin{id,...F0,id,...F2}}"
variables: {input_0: {name: "test", clientMutationId: "0"}}
```

As a result `outputFields.themeEdge.resolve` inside the server-side mutation never get called and I see this message:

```
Warning: writeRelayUpdatePayload(): Expected response payload to include the newly created edge `themeEdge` and its `node` field. Did you forget to update the `RANGE_ADD` mutation config?
```

I've seen [similar issue on github](https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/719). However `REQUIRED_CHILDREN` isn't my case because the application has requested `themes` connection already. Am I missing something obvious? Should I paste more info? Thanks.

react-relay version: `0.6.1`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and eventually solved it by making sure that my equivalent of `themeEdge` actually existed as an edge in my schema. If you grep your schema for `themeEdge`, does an object exist?

For reference, here's my edge definition tailored for you:

```
{
      "name":"themeEdge",
      "description":null,
      "args":[],
      "type":{
        "kind":"NON_NULL",
        "name":null,
        "ofType":{
          "kind":"OBJECT",
          "name":"ThemeEdge",
          "ofType":null
        }
      },
      "isDeprecated":false,
      "deprecationReason":null
    }
```

and

```
{
    "kind":"OBJECT",
    "name":"ThemeEdge",
    "description":"An edge in a connection.",
    "fields":[{
      "name":"node",
      "description":"The item at the end of the edge.",
      "args":[],
      "type":{
        "kind":"NON_NULL",
        "name":null,
        "ofType":{
          "kind":"OBJECT",
          "name":"Theme",
          "ofType":null
        }
      },
      "isDeprecated":false,
      "deprecationReason":null
    }
```

Also note that your `rangeBehaviors` must *exactly* match the query you use to retrieve your parent object. You can specify multiple queries as follows, which also shows the syntax for when your query contains multiple variables:

```
{
    type: 'RANGE_ADD',
    parentName: 'admin',
    parentID: this.props.admin.id,
    connectionName: 'themes',
    edgeName: 'themeEdge',
    rangeBehaviors: {
      '': 'append',
      'first(1).id($adminId)': 'append',
    },
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've posted the cut of schema.json which looks good to me: https://gist.github.com/peresleguine/3dd5772a53a41fe5c68c. An example of server-side mutation would be very helpful.

Comment: I'm using sangria so unless you are too, my server side code probably won't help much. Your schema looks the same as mine though. What's your server side code like?

Comment: I've posted comment to that gist.